# Is the pronoun "it" after the verb "pushed" agreeing with the subject in the following passage?

Tags: grammar

If so, what is the subject that agrees with the boldface pronoun *it* in the passage?

> Matt had never mentioned his father or what he did, because I guess I’d never asked, or maybe I had and didn’t remember during all the long and aimless conversations over our year together, in which topics never got personal until the final week, when I’d pushed **it**, so of course I didn’t know what Matt’s dad did for a living...

(*The Shards: A novel,* by Bret Easton Ellis)

Comment: *it* is not a subject, it is a direct object. "it" is refers to the **topic** of Matt's father.

Comment: Yes, *topic*. Also, *the personal*. And since *You're pushing it* is phrasal for pushing your luck, you can read "I pushed [my luck]. The whole sentence is a stream of consciousness - polite for a major run-on.

Comment: By "agreeing with," do you mean "referring to"?

Comment: @Lambie  Yes.  But are there not contexts in which 'it' is virtually impersonal as an object, for instance "your'e pushing it too far" just as it can be an impersonal subject, as in "it's starting to rain" or "It's getting rather cold in here."?

Comment: @Tuffy Of course, but not here. "it" here refers to the entire situation.

Comment: 'Semi-referential "it" ' (where the 'referent' is deducible). But 'it' in: the conversation? Y the common "Don't push it" is not as easily deducible: the conversation? Your luck? The boat [out]? It's certainly not referential it (where the referent has a corresponding noun etc earlier in the sentence / dialogue).

Comment: @YosefBaskin I would say that the 'it' they were pushing was not their luck but the matter of Matt's father's source of income. Having said that the sentence is far too long and convoluted, it would have been better broken up.

Comment: I think "push it" can be considered a phrasal verb or idiom, and there's no direct referent. When you're asking for information and they're reluctant to answer, "push it" means repeating until they give in.

Comment: Probably **push** sense 4 [to bear hard upon so as to involve in difficulty](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/push).

Comment: I am _not_ asking for the meaning of the sentence fragment _pushed it_ in the context of the passage. I know what it means. I am asking if the pronoun _it_ in the sentence fragment _pushed it_ agrees with the subject, whatever the subject in the passage is. If, as some of you suggested, the pronoun _it_ refers to the word _topics_ - plural - isn't it grammatically incorrect to refer to the word _topics_ - plural - as _it_ instead of _them_?

Comment: @YosefBaskin: The sentence is ridiculously long, sure, but it's not a run-on - there are conjunctions joining all of its many, many clauses...

Comment: Sometimes **it** can be paraphrased as "things".  "...topics never got personal until the final week, when I’d pushed *things*".   That is, "when I became quite relentless in my questioning of Matt *about such matters*".   "things" is a reference to the *semantic* subject or topic, not to a syntactic subject . Same with "it" at times.

Answer (score 2):

Yosef Baskin provides the answer in

> Yes, *topic*. Also, the *personal*. And since You're pushing it is phrasal for pushing your luck, you can read "I pushed [my luck]." The whole sentence is a stream of consciousness - polite for a major run-on. –
> **To push one's luck / to push it**

This is an idiom.

The **it/luck** refers to the success that the narrator has already had from his friendship.

OED

> **P.3.d. to push** (also crowd, ride, etc.) **one's luck**: to take a risk on the assumption that one will continue to be successful or in favour; to rely on good luck.
>
> 2012 ‘You phoned her again? You're pushing your luck,’ Karen said. *D. Park, Light of Amsterdam ii. 31*

Answer (score 1):

No, the pronoun *it* does not agree with any subject in this sentence (if by 'subject' you mean the syntactic definition of that word). I've marked all of the syntactic subjects in the quoted portion of the sentence with squiggly brackets:

> {Matt} had never mentioned his father or what {he} did, because {I} guess {I}’d never asked, or maybe {I} had and didn’t remember during all the long and aimless conversations over our year together, in which {topics} never got personal until the final week, when {I}’d pushed it, so of course {I} didn’t know what {Matt’s dad} did for a living...

None of these are coreferential with the pronoun *it.* Pronouns do not always refer to a previous noun/noun phrase.